# Mongoose query with a list in the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my model, I have this field:

```
…
shows: [{
    startAt: Number,
    endAt: Number
}],
…
```

I need a query to select all objects that have a show that hasn't started yet. In other words, I want to find all models that have at least one `startAt` that is smaller than a given time.

Is this possible? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: It is possible and the query should look about the same as if you were querying an embedded object (you can use the dot notation to access array fields - "shows.starDate"). What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't have any test data, I couldn't test what worked. Now I do, and @joao is absolutely correct.

It seems like Mongoose doesn't care that `shows` is a list. It was as simple as writing

`<model>.find().where('shows.startAt').gt(<constant>).exec(callback);`